# How to insert currently logged in username into a SQL table using ADO.NET (MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am writing a POST method in my controller that adds an item through a form in razor page. My table in MSSQL has a **username** column which indicates the currently loggedin user in Windows (i.e. jdoe). By that means, I want the username to be inserted in the table automatically every time a form is submitted, so that the db can keep track of who submitted which item.
This is the snippet of the code in my function where I am trying to insert the current user:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUserName", ); //I don't know what to write to get and add the currently loggedin user
```

What should I do to INSERT the current username?

Comment: Specifically, is the problem *inserting into the database* or is the problem *getting the current username*?  Separate these things so one doesn't get in the way of the other.  Does `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` contain the expected username value or not?  What value does it contain?

Comment: I edited the snippet. I looked up an example online but it is not working. I honestly don't know what should I write on the parameter

Comment: So the question you're trying to ask is how to get the current logged in username in your application?  Nothing to do with the database?  In that case... How specifically is your application tracking authentication/authorization?  Are there any other places in the application where you *have* successfully used the username?

Comment: No. This is the only part where I am trying to get and insert the currently logged in Windows username (active directory) into the database. Something like  GetUserName from "advapi32.dll in vb.

Comment: And how specifically is your application tracking authentication/authorization?  If you've never read the username before, *is there* even a username?  What username value are you expecting to observe and why?

Comment: The username is the one that I login with every time I start computer.

Comment: Are you saying that you've *specifically* configured your web application to use Windows Authentication?  Can you clarify that configuration?  Because currently it sounds like you just have a web application with *no* authentication and no knowledge of who any given user is.  Please understand that we know *nothing* of your application and take some time to clarify the specifics of the problem in the question above.

Comment: not the current logged in username of my application, but from my PC. The web app does not have its own login feature.

Comment: You appear to be misunderstanding how web applications work.  Depending on how you host/run the web application, the application *itself* may be under a different user context than you are.  You can potentially get that context, but it won't be of much use to you if it's a different user (a system account of some kind).  Nor will that tell you anything about other users connecting to the application.  Those users may not even *have* a "Windows username* as they may not even be using Windows.  Nor are they likely to be *sending you* that username.

Comment: If you want your web application to know which user is accessing it, you need to add authentication to your web application.  Windows authentication is likely an option.  Though any user accessing it would need an account on that same Windows domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searches and helps from others, `Environment.Username` did my job.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=net-7.0